# universal references and overloads

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have two overloads of a method in a class, `set_value` which each take a universal reference. I'd like to have one function call the other to avoid code duplication, but I'm not sure which is the correct way to give the universal reference to the other function.

```
template <typename U>
void set_value(U&& value) {
    this->value_ = std::forward<U>(value);
}

template <typename U>
void set_value(U&& value, int overloaded) {
    // which is the correct way to use the other `set_value` overload?
    set_value(value); // just use value directly?
    set_value(std::forward<U>(value)); // or should I forward it?
}
```

Comment: Usually you'd `forward` it, but there might be rare exceptions, depending on what that overload is supposed to do.

Comment: The name `value` in `set_value` is an lvalue, so `set_value(value);` would result in the one-parameter overload being called with an lvalue reference. Use `forward` if you want perfect forwarding of the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want perfect forwarding of `value`, use `std::forward`

Even though `value` *might* be bound to an rvalue, when you use it by name inside `set_value` it is an lvalue. Therefore, if you do `set_value(value);` the universal reference in the one-parameter overload would be bound to an lvalue reference.

We can confirm this by adding doing something like this:

```
template<class T> class TD;  // Allows us to view type deduction results in
                             // the form of compilation errors.
                             // (From "Effective Modern C++")

...

template <typename U>
void set_value(U&& value) {
    TD<decltype(value)> td;
}

...

int i;
set_value(i, 0);
set_value(3, 0);
```

When forwarding is used, this will give you a compilation error that will reveal the type of `value` to be `int&` for `set_value(i, 0);`. If you comment out that statement you'll get a compilation error for `set_value(3, 0);` revealing the type of `value` to be `int&&`.
If you remove the forwarding you'll get `int&` in both cases.